# How to use GroupBy in nested query in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, group-by, subquery

I have four tables in the database i.e. Packages, Fixtures, Deals and Fixtures Deals.

Here are the table structure details:

```
Packages: id, title
Fixtures: id, package_id, name
Deals: id, discound, description
Fixtures_Deal: id, fixture_id, deal_id, price
```

I need to get the packages list along with the minimum deal price that offers in each fixture for each package.

Here is the mysql query I run in phpMyAdmin or SQLYog, and it works perfectly, but in Laravel it gives me "p.title' isn't in GROUP BY" error.

```
SELECT 
  p.title AS package_title,      
  tbl_min_value.min_price AS min_price 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    fixture_id,
    MIN(deal_price) AS min_price 
  FROM
    fixture_deal 
  GROUP BY fixture_id) AS tbl_min_value 
  JOIN fixtures AS f 
    ON f.id = tbl_min_value.fixture_id 
  RIGHT JOIN packages AS p 
    ON f.package_id = p.id 
GROUP BY p.id
```

By the way, I'm trying to achieve it by using the following method in model:

```
return DB::statement('SELECT 
      p.title AS package_title,      
      tbl_min_value.min_price AS min_price 
    FROM
      (SELECT 
        fixture_id,
        MIN(deal_price) AS min_price 
      FROM
        fixture_deal 
      GROUP BY fixture_id) AS tbl_min_value 
      JOIN fixtures AS f 
        ON f.id = tbl_min_value.fixture_id 
      RIGHT JOIN packages AS p 
        ON f.package_id = p.id 
    GROUP BY p.id');
```

Comment: have you tried to execute it another way, like `$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();` and fire it directly

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. Can you please elaborate how can I do that?

Should I write a code like this?:
DB::connection()->getPdo('Query');

Comment: https://codeshare.io/29QA72

Comment: Nope... it still gives almost the same error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'p.title' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: what happens if you replace p.title by id?

Comment: 'tbl_min_value.min_price' isn't in GROUP BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another way around by using Eloquent Collection's `mapWithKeys` method.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-mapwithkeys
```

So I fetched the data of two queries separately and map both the collections with keys into one collection object.

Sample Code:

```
$packages = Package::getPackages();

$deal_min_price = Deal::getMinimumPrice();

$packages_with_price = $packages->mapWithKeys(function ($packages) use ($deal_min_price) {
    return $packages['price'] => $deal_min_price['min_price'];
});
```

You may either use `foreach` loop within the `mapWithKey's closure`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because MySQL 5.7 moved to be more compliant with SQL99. You can read a bit about that [here](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2014/09/mysql-575-group-by-respects-functional.html), but it involves a SQL mode setting called `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` that ensures any non-aggregated columns being selected are inside the `GROUP BY`. What does this mean for your situation?

Well, you simply need to add `p.title` and `tbl_min_value.min_price` to the grouping for it to work correctly, since they are not aggregated:

```
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, tbl_min_value.min_price
```

You may be wondering, "Why on earth would they do that?". Well, using `GROUP BY`, before it was easy to accidentally "collapse" down data where a row had more than one possible value it could display, so it just showed the first one. This makes you figure out what you want to show using an aggregate function such as `MIN()` or `MAX()`, or add it to the grouping indicating you want them separated.

If you don't like the way this works, you can disable it temporarily by doing this:

```
# Run this query and copy the values
SELECT @@sql_mode;

# Remove "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" and paste it in here where the XXX is
SET sql_mode = 'XXX';
```

Or you can make that change permanent by editing your `my.cnf` file under the `[mysqld]` section like this, where XXX is the output of `SELECT @@sql_mode;` minus the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY part:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=XXX
```

Comment: Once I added other aggregated columns in Group By, it doesn't give me an appropriate results, meaning it output results with duplicate IDs, that is the problem.

Additionally, I have tried to modify the SQL Mode but it didn't work though.

Comment: That's because you have more than one row with the same ID as a result of your joins. Try `GROUP_CONCAT(p.title)` and/or `GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_min_value.min_price)` to see what I mean

Comment: Also I was wondering that the same query having one Group By column works well in phpMyAdmn or SQLYog, but it doesn't work in Laravel 5.3. So this might be an issue with Laravel... Not sure..!

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that a SQL query is working fine in phpMyAdmin but the same is not working in Laravel 5.3. Would you post the db structure with sample data, so we take a look?

BTW, I tried following SQL and is working fine in `Laravel 5.2`:

```
SELECT 
  p.title AS package_title,      
  tbl_min_value.min_price AS min_price 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    fixture_id,
    MIN(deal_price) AS min_price 
  FROM
    fixtures_deal 
  GROUP BY fixture_id) AS tbl_min_value 
  JOIN fixtures AS f 
    ON f.id = tbl_min_value.fixture_id 
  RIGHT JOIN packages AS p 
    ON f.package_id = p.id 
GROUP BY p.id
```